# How to create a list out of multiple labels given in a column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with 2 columns...image name and its corresponding multiple labels. I want to convert it to a multiple binarizer vector. But i am getting error.

I have tried sklearn's `MultipleBinarizer` directly on the second column of labels.

`df["labels"][0]` gives:

```
['label1', 'label2', 'label3']
```

`df.head()` gives `image name ['label1','label2']` etc.

I want to get the binarizer for this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and it worked for me. I am sure there are other ways but hope this helps.
My input file looks like below
[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
file = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\t')
y = file['label'].apply(lambda f: f.split(','))
binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
one_hot = binarizer.fit_transform(y.values)
print(one_hot, binarizer.classes_)
```

Comment: From your question, I can only guess that it would have been because your labels are in an array. We need to split values before calling fit_transform.